# Considering The Transfomer modell: What is fed from the encoder stack to the decoder layers

Tags: neural-network, transformer-model, attention-model

I'm trying to properly understand the transformer architecture. I have difficulties figuring out, what kind of data ist actually fed from the encoder stack to the decoder stack.

Considering the "Attention is all you need" Paper by Google(https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.03762.pdf (pdf)) and the blog post by Jay Allamar(http://jalammar.github.io/illustrated-transformer/) I get that attention is performed "over all the output of the encoder stack"(Paper). Now I am wondering about two things: 1. How is the decoder stack initialized, is there a fixed or trained decoder state D0 or something or is it also initialized by the output of the encoder stack. 2. What can I picture this "output of the encoder state" to be like? As this is an encoder-decoder structure I'd expect it to be some kind of context vector. In another blog post by Jay Allamar(https://jalammar.github.io/visualizing-neural-machine-translation-mechanics-of-seq2seq-models-with-attention/) it seems like it is a concatenation or stack of the hidden states of the encoder layers. However, in the blog post mentioned first as well as in the paper it sounds more like these hidden states are only fed to the subsequent encoder layer and not stored in any way. So what is the decoder actually attending to?